# reshaping 3D matrix into 2D matrix using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape

I have a 3D matrix of dimensions, `549x19x50` I need to create  a 2D matrix which gets me a `549x950` matrix.

What i did so far is using tensorflow;

```
#data_3d is the 3D matrix
data_2d = tf.reshape(data_3d,[549,-1])
```

This prints out all the values of data_3d in the prompt and when I try to access data_2d it gives me an NameError

data_3d is a list of list of lists. Not a tensor or a ndarray. If we cant do this for lists, is there any way to easily convert lists to ndarrays?

Thanks in advance,

Bhashithe

Comment: Why just Tensorflow?

Comment: I need to use a recurrent neural network with tensorflow. Which I have been testing and and quite familiar with right now. I can use any other python library if you can point me towards something @GalDreiman

Comment: So look at the answers, I'll post an answer based on `numpy` with a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple way to do so using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

data_3d = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
data_2d = data_3d.swapaxes(1,2).reshape(3,-1)
```

**Ouput:**

```
data_2d
```

[[ 0  3  6  1  4  7  2  5  8]
 [ 9 12 15 10 13 16 11 14 17]
 [18 21 24 19 22 25 20 23 26]]

```
print data_3d
```

[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]]

**Note**: `swapaxes(1,2)` is the main thing here - you need to define which axes you want to swap.

Comment: this worked without any swapaxes(). I didn't understand why you added swapaxes in your answer.

Comment: So you specifically choose what axes to swap and not just reshape.

Comment: that makes sense. But in my case swapping was not necessary. Cool to know that. Thanks Gal!